# Developer PowerShell for Visual Studio 2022 is corrupted

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio

Get these two messages when trying to open Developer PowerShell for Visual Studio 2022:

Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

I'm totally new to programming, so please explain in an easy step-by-step way how to fix this error in Visual Studio.

Have tried to reinstall Visual Studio, but didn't work.

Discovered that I can open the powershell from within VS but not when using search in Windows 10 to get the list which shows the app. The app icon for the powershell is not there, and get the above-mentioned error messages when trying to run the app as administrator

Comment: I would perform a in-place repair install of Windows 10. It appears PowerShell 5.1 which is built-into Windows 10 is corrupt. There is no way to reinstall PowerShell 5.1 without reinstalling Windows 10. Your issue has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: It worked! Thank you :)  :)