# How to completely uninstall Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I've tried uninstalling from both control panel in Windows 10 and in the VS Installer (by clicking "More" there and then "Uninstall"). Have also searched in File Explorer to delete all files related to VS. But when I reinstall VS it keeps installing in the old location where I no longer want it to be installed. It installs under C:\Users\ ...\sources\repos As far as I know it's meant to be installed in Program Files (x86), right? Furthermore, when I reinstall, I don't get an option to choose where to install VS. It just automatically installs at C:\Users...\sources\repos

Before reinstalling, I have also tried without success to delete in Registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\SharedInstallationPath

Any way to fix this?

I ask because I'm trying to install the Msvc compiler from Microsoft, in order to properly set up Visual Studio Code for C++, and the freecodeCamp.org Youtube video, called C++ Programming Course - Beginner to Advanced, says that I must use the Developer PowerShell Visual Studio 2022 to do that, but the PowerShell is corrupted, as I have explained here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1741651/developer-powershell-for-visual-studio-2022-is-corrupted

I have therefore tried to uninstall Visual Studio, and reinstall it, to see if that solves the problem with the VS PowerShell, but it seems like a complete uninstall isn't possible, at least the VS PowerShell keeps being broken when trying to launch it as an app from "Search" in Windows 10.

Anyway, is there another way than using the VS Powershell to "connect" Visual Studio Code to the Msvc compiler?

I'm totally new to programming, so please explain in an easy step-by-step manner. Thanks in advance  :)  :)

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#uninstall-visual-studio-1) help?

Comment: I am not sure that Visual Studio 2022 has anything to do with your powershell issue. You may just want to install the latest from here: [https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.2.6](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.2.6)

Comment: ***Anyway, is there another way than using the VS Powershell to "connect" Visual Studio Code to the Msvc compiler?*** Yes you don't have to use powershell at all: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729130/visual-studio-code-how-to-switch-from-powershell-exe-to-cmd-exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729130/visual-studio-code-how-to-switch-from-powershell-exe-to-cmd-exe)

Comment: Have you tried using [InstallCleanup.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#:~:text=Uninstall%20Visual%20Studio%201%20In%20Windows%2010%20or,find%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Installer.%205%20Choose%20Uninstall.) per Microsoft’s instructions?

Comment: Why was this migrated when there is a duplicate with an answer to the author’s question?

Answer (score 0):

I got this suggestion at superuser.com:

"I would perform a in-place repair install of Windows 10. It appears PowerShell 5.1 which is built-into Windows 10 is corrupt. There is no way to reinstall PowerShell 5.1 without reinstalling Windows 10. Your issue has nothing to do with Visual Studio."

I'm doing it now, hope it works, and thanks for all the suggestions! Great to have a community that has the patience and kindness to teach others how to code and use software properly.

Edit: it worked! Developer Powershell for VS 2022 opens now when using search in Windows 10 and clicking on the app listed there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).